# Write Unicode UTF-8 and UTF-16 data into a QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, encoding, windows-xp, utf

I'm developing a protocol for my company using Qt. It is required to query the Window Registry and write the value obtained into a prenegotiated socket. I have read the Registry Data into a `QString`. I must use 8-bit Unicode characters and for some 16-bit Unicode characters. I am using `QByteArray` to store all the data before writing to the socket using `QTcpSocket::write()`. Little Endianness must be followed.

1. How do I get the data from `QString` into `QByteArray` in Unicode 8 bit format (specification says character type corresponds to `quint8`)?
2. How do I get the data from `QString` into `QByteArray` in Unicode 16 bit format (specification says character type corresponds to `quint16`)?
3. How can I maintain Little Endianness in all cases?

(I have no experience of dealing with Unicode/variable-byte-encoded data)

Comment: There are no 8-bit or 16-bit Unicode characters. Unicode is a 21-bit code. Do you perhaps refer to UTF-8 and UTF-16 (which use 8-bit or 16-bit code *units* to represent Unicode *code points*)?

Comment: @Joey maybe that's what the specification meant (what you wrote) but this is the way it says (what i wrote). Going by what you say is what is required, how would i do it?

Comment: @ustulation Both are preferable to leaving questions unanswered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking in the documentation is a good start.

1. [QString::toUtf8()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#toUtf8)
2. Create a new QByteArray starting with a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark#UTF-16). Use [QString::utf16()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#utf16) to get the ushort values, mask out the top and bottom halves in the endianness you want into the QByteArray.
3. UTF-8 doesn't have/need endianness. The ushort masks needed to put 16-bit values into an 8-bit array for little endianness would be `0x00FF` then `0xFF00`.
4. Read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) at home tonight.

Comment: Couldn't put it any better myself. An *excellent* answer! [Rushes to print 'The Absolute Minimum...' himself]

Answer (score 2):

For your question # 2 - How to convert QString to UTF-16 QByteArray, there is a solution with QTextCodec::fromUnicode(), as shown in the following code example:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTextCodec>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    // QString to QByteArray
    // =====================

    QString qstr_test = "test"; // from QString
    qDebug().noquote().nospace() << "qstr_test[" << qstr_test << "]";     // Should see: qstr_test[test]

    QTextCodec * pTextCodec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-16");

    QByteArray qba_test = pTextCodec->fromUnicode(qstr_test); // to UTF-16 QByteArray
    qDebug() << "qba_test[";
    int test_size = qba_test.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < test_size; ++i) { // Should see each UTF-16 encoded character per line like this: ÿþt e s t
        qDebug() << qba_test.at(i);
    }
    qDebug() << "]";

    return a.exec();
}
```

The above code has been tested using Qt 5.4.